# Using jquery to show div if all above value's in form are true to criteria

Tags: javascript, html

For the most part I have this code working. I originally had it so that if the email field length was greater than 10 then on `keyup` a div below would show. That worked okay. However, I want to add more validation. Below is my jQuery and I'm not sure I'm using the correct syntax.

```
$('#primaryemail').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val().length > 11 && ('#first_name').val().length > 6 && ('#phone_number').val().length == 10)
    $('#projectinfo').show();
        else
    $('#projectinfo').hide();
});
```

I'm sure where I went wrong is with the `&&` operators getting that from JavaScript and not entirely positive this is the correct way with jQuery.

Originally I had just the `primaryemail` as the validation but then added the `first_name` & `phone_number` as well. Once I added that it didn't work.

Comment: what's the problem actually?

Comment: Originally I had just the primaryemail as the validation but then added the first_name & phone_number as well. Once I added that it didn't work.

Comment: Where is the PHP? This is jQuery.

Comment: @PHPglue sorry... jquery... derp

Comment: you need to put OR operator(||)rather than &&. Please put there and try

Comment: This code includes only Javascript and no PHP. I think you are missing a `$` before `('#first_name')` and `('#phone_number')`. It is difficult to help without seeing the relevant HTML, could you post that as well?

Answer (score 0):

It might help to check your syntax and break it to multiple lines:

```
$('#primaryemail').keyup(function(){
    if(
        $(this).val().length > 11 // I suggest you also use .trim()
        && $('#first_name').val().length > 6
        && $('#phone_number').val().length == 10
    ) { // Always helpful to use Brackets
        $('#projectinfo').show();
    } else { // Especially around 'else' 
        $('#projectinfo').hide();
    }
});
```

My suggested alternative is this:

```
// Cache your variables, noting the comma at the end of the first
// three lines, and the semicolon at the end of the 4th one.
// If you add more, use a comma after each one except the last one.
var $firstName    = $('#first_name'),
    $primaryEmail = $('#primary_email'),
    $phoneNumber  = $('#phone_number'),
    $projectInfo  = $('#projectinfo');

// Now bind your event listeners
// and use a simple function name to keep it easy!
$primaryEmail.keyup(function(){
    if(isValidData()) {
        $projectInfo.show();
    } else {
        $projectInfo.hide();
    }
});

// Create a function for your logic that return a simple Boolean
// This keeps your state checking separate from your actions
// which rely on that state.  You may check states in multiple places
// so it might be helpful to put them in separate functions to avoid
// repetition in the future.
function isValidData(){
    return (
        11 < $primaryEmail.val().trim().length
        && 6 < $firstName.val().trim().length
        && 10 == $phoneNumber.val().trim().length
    );
}
```

Comment: Using the known data (numbers in this case) on the left of a comparison or equality operator is often difficult to do at the beginning, but it makes it far less likely to accidentally assign a value to a variable, which won't throw an error, whereas the above approach will, if you make a mistake..